# Jgraph (vanilla): how to set edge label, ProM-specific

Tags: java, jgraph

I'm currently writing a plugin for ProM in case someone is familiar with it. In general, there is a graph, represented as `ProMJGraph`, which is directly derived from `JGraph`.

This graph contains:

- `ProMGraphEdge`'s (direct child of `org.jgraph.graph.DefaultEdge`) and
- `ProMGraphCell`'s (direct child of `org.jgraph.graph.DefaultGraphCell`).

I have to put labels onto the edges.
For example I stored a pointer to the first edge of the graph named `jgraph` to the variable `e0`, of type `ProMGraphEdge`.

I failed to google out, where and what should I now call in order to set the label «hello» for the edge `e0`?

---

<strike>If anyone at list has a link to JGraph manual, please post it here. I failed to find a referencebook for jgraph and NOT JGraphX, nor JGraphT.</strike>

upd. Found it: http://touchflow.googlecode.com/hg-history/75fada644b2a19c744130923cbd34747fba861a2/doc/jgraphmanual.pdf

upd2. I found chapter 3.5.2 «Using edges» which should contain the answer to my question. It's probably ProM-specific that the source provided in the pdf does not work for me. Maybe if there is anyone exprienced in the Process Miner (ProM), he/she can give me some hint if there is something tricky about `ProMJGraph`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It occured to be ProM-specific.

The section 3.5.2 of the pdf mentioned in the question contains the answer about how to add a label to a plain JGraph, and I had to use a bit different code to get any effect:

```
newArc = addArc(places.get(src), transitions.get(dest));
if (label != null) {        
    AttributeMap amap = newArc.getAttributeMap();
    amap.put(AttributeMap.LABEL, "Hello world");
    amap.put(AttributeMap.SHOWLABEL, true);
    amap.put(AttributeMap.LABELALONGEDGE, true);
}
```

This code resides in a class derived from `AbstractResetInhibitorNet`, the instance of which is called `graph`. This instance is later converted to a JGraph with a code

```
ProMJGraphPanel visualizeGraph(PluginContext context,
                               CPNGraph graph, // instanceof AbstractResetInhibitorNet
                               ViewSpecificAttributeMap map) {
    ProMGraphModel model = new ProMGraphModel(graph);
    GraphLayoutConnection layoutConnection = new GraphLayoutConnection(graph);
    layoutConnection.expandAll();
    ProMJGraph jgraph = new ProMJGraph(model, map, layoutConnection);
    ...
}
```